# Пауза для процесса yt-dlp

Tags: python

Сделал для yt-dlp вот такой код для паузы при скачивании видео, всё просто, всё работает, по нажатии F2 процесс yt-dlp приостанавливается. Это работает если отдельно запущен yt-dlp в консоли и отдельно этот код.
Но вот вместе в одном коде не знаю как реализовать их работу, добавил на F4 запуск yt-dlp и пауза F2 уже не работает. Как сделать чтоб вместе это работало?

```
processes = [p for p in psutil.process_iter(['name', 'status']) if p.info['name'] == "yt-dlp.exe"]

def YTD_proc():
    for process in processes:
        if process.status() == "running":process.suspend()
        elif process.status() == "stopped":process.resume()
    print(f'YT-DLP.exe is {processes[0].status()}')

def YTD_run():
    subprocess.run('yt-dlp.exe --continue --merge-output-format mp4 --format "137+140" -a links.txt')

keyboard.add_hotkey('F4', YTD_run)
keyboard.add_hotkey('F2', YTD_proc)
while True:pass
```

Comment: Сделал через трединг вот так, если кому интересно будет:

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    keyboard.add_hotkey('F4', lambda: threading.Thread(target=YTD_run).start())
    keyboard.add_hotkey('F2', lambda: threading.Thread(target=YTD_proc).start())
    keyboard.wait()`